# What is exactly relationship between scheme $X$ and its global sections in comparison to $C^\star$ algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, algebraic-geometry, c-star-algebras

This is just random thought based upon Iitaka's Algebraic Geometry Thm 1.15 proof. Let $X$ be a scheme and denote $A(X)$ ring of global sections of $X$ associated to the scheme. In the proof of $Spec,A(-)$ adjunction(to see adjunction, use $Sch^{op}$ category instead), $Hom_{Sch}(X,Spec B)\cong Hom_{Ring}(B,A(X))$, the book constructed an arrow $X\to Spec(A(X))$ which enjoys universal arrow property.

In other words, given $X\to Spec(B)$, the map $X\to Spec(B)$ factors through $X\to Spec(A(X))\to Spec(B)$.

Recall Gelfand transform.(in accordance to Lang's Real and Functional Analysis book.) Let $A$ be a commutative Banach algebra. Let $M$ be the set of maximal ideals of $A$. Now we have $A\to C(M,C)$ map where $M$ is really in bijection to characters of $A$. So in effectives $A\to C(\hat{A},C)$ where $\hat{A}$ is the set of characters and this map is given by evaluation.

$\textbf{Q:}$ It is clear that $A(X)$ is functions globally defined over $X$. Both construction maps starting space into a function space. What is exactly analogy between them?(i.e. $X\to Spec(A(X))$ and $A\to C(\hat{A},C)$) Note that $X\to Spec(A(X))$ is an injection for topological space and for sheaves, there is no guarantee to be injection whereas $A\to C(\hat{A},C)$ is just a map which may not be bijection unless $A$ is commutative unital Banach algebra.

Comment: I think historically this might have been part of the motivation of the definition of a scheme. You should however be careful that there are many schemes for which $A(X)$ does not remember anything about $X$

Comment: You need $X$ to be an affine scheme $X = Spec(R)$. For finitely generated commutative $k$-algebra $R = k[X]/I$ (those we care of in algebraic geometry) "the set of continuous characters $A\to \Bbb{C}$" translates to "the set of $k$-algebra homomorphisms $R \to \overline{k}$" which corresponds exactly to the affine variety $V(I)$ (without its scheme and Zariski topology structure)